# Replace at every 5th semicolon

Tags: regex, hive, udf

I was wondering if i'ts possible to use hive's `regexp_replace` at every nth in my case I would like to replace every 5th semicolon with pipe

example of column data:

```
test;vid;1;;1.45;id:3;manlyman;2;4;;
```

So there would be 2 replaces in this one. This can't be a static replace because some times the column data will have only 5 or sometimes 15.

Comment: Can't test it, try pattern like `((?:[^;]*;){4}[^;]*);` and replace with `$1|` [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW1rF4/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use String.replaceAll() with the pattern mentioned by @bobble Bubble :

```
int nth = 5;
String input ="test;vid;1;;1.45;id:3;manlyman;2;4;;";   
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(([^;]*;){"+(nth-1)+"}[^;]*);", "$1|"));
```

Output:

> test;vid;1;;1.45|id:3;manlyman;2;4;|